# Instead of attacking the Russian convoy to Kyiv itself, would it be political advantageous to bombard the access road(s) to the Ukrainian capital?

Tags: armed-conflict, military, ukraine

[image: russian convoy]

AFAFP PHOTO / SATELLITE IMAGE  Copyright 2022 MAXAR TECHNOLOGIES

An enormous Russian convoy, over 60 km long, has approached to 20 km distance north of the [Ukrainian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine) capital [Kyiv.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyiv)
Military experts are astonished about the route of this convoy through a wooded area with small roads which makes it very vulnerable.

Why don't the [Ukrainians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine) bombard these roads in order to obstruct this convoy to surround and then occupy the capitel ?

Comment: This question might date quite quickly. However, i suspect that things are not always as they seem. Looks like an easy target to us but we are not there. I suspect that freedom in the air is not rnjoyed by those opposing Russell forces

Comment: Welcome to Politics Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, this question is not suited to this site. It’s not really about government policy so much as specific military tactics so answers would have to speculate about the unknowable internal motivations of generals.

Comment: These are tanks and tracked vehicles (which can go offroad).  Probably with full complements of combat engineers.  Even if Ukraine's air force was not the underdog, any damage to the road would quickly be either fixed or bypassed.  That said, they do look like very tempting targets, all neatly lined up.

Comment: Russia has air supremacy in Ukraine now.

Comment: It might be a valid history question, but not a politics question, or where is the connection to politics?

Comment: I suspect we will see a turning point in the reporting of this conflict. Soviet softening up of the targets, absorbing the opfor ammunition stores, ground and/or air tactical and strategic recon reduced, less concern for collateral damage, constant pouring of manpower into the AO...